# Create new user without typing current user password

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

On a VPS, I need to create a new user on PostgreSQL 9.3 so I have tried

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create user new_user with password 'secret';"
```

This works but it asks me for the current user (deploy) password before proceeding and since I'm running it from a Capistrano task the shall is not interactive so I cannot input the password.

Is there a way to create a new PostgreSQL user without inputting the current user password?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6405127/330315

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I have tried already to create a  `~/.pgpass` file. It looks like `localhost:5432:*:deploy:deploypwd` but the password is still required.

Comment: You did create the `~./pgpass` in the home directory of the `postgres` user, did you? Because of the `sudo` command that's where `psql` will be looking. Btw, the `sudo` is not really necessary you can supply the DB user to psql directly.

Comment: Nope in the home directory of the `deploy` user. Opps.
In /home I have just the 'deploy' folder.

Comment: If you are running that as the `deploy` user, then don't use `sudo` but specfiy `-U postgres` to login as the superuser in psql

Comment: An alternative to `.pgpass` is setting `pg_hba.conf` u to allow `peer` auth for the `postgres` user, then sudo'ig to `postgres` to do work like this. In fact, that's the default on most distros. You didn't mention how you installed PostgreSQL or what OS/distro/version you're on, though.

Comment: I have removed `~/.pgpass` and added to `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` the following `local all all trust' (commented out all other local entries) but still I need to input the deploy password (after restarting the service). The VPS is running Ubuntu 12.04 and PG 9.3 installed by simply running `apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3` (as explained http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).
If I try to run the command without sudo: `-u postgres psql -c "create user new_user with password 'secret';"` I get `-bash: -u: command not found`. THANKS GUYS FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: I would try this.. https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-postgresql